# How to get matchers work with aggregation for date ranges?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model that has author (that is mongoose.Schema.ObjectId), and I have a date field on that model (type Date).

It **works** when I do this, the data comes back:

```
MyModel.find({
    author: req.user._id,
    started: {
      $gte: start,
      $lte: end
    }
  });
```

But I have an aggregation function in my Schema, this is how it looks like:

```
myModelSchema.statics.getSomeData = function getSomeData(id, start, end) {
  const query = [
    { $sort: { started: 1 } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'projects',
        localField: 'project',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'projectdata'
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tasks',
        localField: 'task',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'taskdata'
      }
    }
  ];
  if (start && end) {
    query.unshift({
      $match: {
        $and: [{ started: { $gte: start, $lte: end } }, { author: id }]
      }
    });
  } else {
    query.unshift({ $match: { author: id } });
  }
  return this.aggregate(query);
};
```

**Note**: The part where I push the matcher for the author, that gets me all the data with the current author **works**, but the part where I also want the data to come back within date range doesn't work, the data comes empty, **when** the start and end dates are passed to the static function.

Date format I pass to the aggregation function: **'2018-11-04 06:00:00'** (a string).

Comment: can you update the date format in the description you are passing in start and end date?

Comment: @AlokDeshwal yep, done.

Comment: you are passing string, but it should a date object, so just create date object from this string and pass it or you can just pass the string to `new Date(datestringgoeshere)`

Comment: @AlokDeshwal, that did it. Thanks a TON, idk why it didn't cross my mind. Anyway, if you wish answer the question, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are matching a date object with string value that wouldn't work at all, So value also should be a date object

```
myModelSchema.statics.getSomeData = function getSomeData(id, start, end) {
const query = [
    { $sort: { started: 1 } },
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'projects',
        localField: 'project',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'projectdata'
    }
    },
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'tasks',
        localField: 'task',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'taskdata'
    }
    }
];
if (start && end) {
    query.unshift({
    $match: {
        $and: [{ started: { $gte: new Date(start), $lte: new Date(end) } }, { author: id }]
    }
    });
} else {
    query.unshift({ $match: { author: id } });
}
return this.aggregate(query);
};
```